# NetLogo - unilaterally exchange values of nearby turtles

Tags: netlogo

With regard to this question ([NetLogo - calculate the difference of a variable of neighbouring agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637192/netlogo-calculate-the-difference-of-a-variable-of-neighbouring-agents)), I am trying to change (for another scenario) the code so that another breed can change unilaterally the values of nearby members of the other breed (if their values are above a certain threshold) and by means of randomness can even change the value of one of (any) distant member of the other breed.

My code is (pseudo code in brackets):

```
breed [ greens green ]
greens-own [ variable ]

breed [ reds red ]

to setup    
    create-greens 100 [
        set variable random 10    
    ]  
    create-reds 1
end

to start
   ask reds [
   exchange
   ]
end

to exchange
  rt random 360
  fd 0.5
  ask reds-on neighbors [
      let both-turtles (turtle-set self myself)
      "greens with variable > 6.9" [ set variable variable + 0.5]
 ]
 "one-of greens [ set variable variable + 1]"
end
```

How can I convert the pseudo-code to NetLogo code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any turtle can instruct any turtle to change values with `ask`. you can simply state something like `ask one-of greens [ set variable variable + 1]` or `ask greens with [variable > 6.9][...]`. You need to take some care here, though, because you will be asking every red on a neighbour to ask ALL greens to change variable value as currently pseudo-coded.

Comment: Thank you, JenB. This has helped me. :)